# Pass command line arguments to nose via "python setup.py test"

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, nose, setup.py

## Package Settings

I have built a Python package which uses [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for testing. Therefore, `setup.py` contains:

```
..
test_suite='nose.collector',
tests_require=['nose'],
..
```

And `python setup.py test` works as expected:

```
running test
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.065s

OK
```

## Running with XUnit output

Since I'm using Jenkins CI, I would like to output the nose results to JUnit XML format:

```
nosetests <package-name> --with-xunit --verbose
```

However, `python setup.py test` is far more elegant, and it installs the test requirements without having to build a virtual environment.

**Is there a way to pass the `--with-xunit` (or any other parameter) to nose, when calling nose via `python setup.py test`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nose provides its own setuptools command (`nosetests`) which accepts command line arguments:

```
python setup.py nosetests --with-xunit
```

More information can be found here:
http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools_integration.html

Answer (score 3):

You can set nosetests option using `setup.cfg`

For example in you `setup.cfg`

```
[nosetests]
with-xunit=1
```

Further information can be found at http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/commands.html